# SpringData JPA: Query with collection of entity as parameter

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a list of entities on which I want to perform an update, I know I could update the table with list of String/Integer.. etc as the parameter with something like

```
  @Query("update tableName i set i.isUpdated = true where i.id in :ids")
  void markAsUpdated(@Param("ids") List<Integer> itemIds);
```

I'm trying to avoid repeated conversion of list of entities to list of Ids for making the query in DB. I know there are `deleteAll` and `deleteInBatch` commands which accept parameter as list of entities.

How do I do this in JPA Query, I tried the following but it didn't work yet.

```
  @Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)
  @Query("update tableName i set i.updated = true where i in :items")
  void markAsUpdated(@Param("items") List<Item> items)
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible, and if you look at the implementation of `SimpleJpaRepository.deleteInBatch`, you'll realize that converting entities to list of ids is the lesser of two evils.

Comment: Also, if by 'repeated conversion', you mean having to do the conversion in multiple locations around your code, note that you can simply implement your second method as a default method delegating to the first one

Comment: @crizzis Thanks, by repeated conversion I mean for different entities with similar queries, I need to repeat the conversions, I can't delegate different entity conversion to same method, right? At least not without using some hacks. I'll stick to ids I think.

Answer (score 1):

The query needs ids, it doesn't know how to deal with entities.

You have multiple options:

- Just pass ids to the method, the client is responsible for extracting ids.
- Pass entities and use SpEL for extracting ids
- As suggested in the comments use a default method to offer both APIs and to delegate from one to the other.

As for the question that came up in the comments: You can move the method for extracting the id into a single method by either have relevant entities implement an interface similar to this one:

```
interface WithId {
    Long getId();
}
```

Or by passing a lambda to the method, doing the conversion for a single entity:

```
List<ID> extractIds(List<E> entities, Function<E, ID> extractor) {
    // ...
}
```